API Password Change Issue - Laravel 11.x
I'm working on a Laravel project, and I've created a password change API. Here's the route I'm using:
Route::post('/change-password', function (Request $request) {
    // Validate the request data
    $request->validate([
        'current_password' => 'required|string',
        'new_password' => 'required|string|confirmed|min:8',
    ]);

    // Check if the current password matches the user's current password
    if (!Hash::check($request->current_password, $request->user()->password)) {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'The provided current password does not match your current password.',
        ], 422);
    }

    // Update the user's password
    $request->user()->password = bcrypt($request->new_password);
    $request->user()->save();

    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Password has been changed successfully.',
    ], 200);
})->middleware('auth:sanctum')->name('password.change');

When I test this I get status code 200 but, password is not changed.
[I am not looking for reset password, I am looking for change password for authenticated user.]
I tried : user()->updated(), AI chatbot.

Update your code like below
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

Route::post('/change-password', function (Request $request) {
    $validated = $request->validate([
        'current_password' => 'required|current_password',
        'new_password' => 'required|confirmed|min:8',
    ]);

    $request->user()->update([
        'password' => Hash::make($validated['password']),
    ]);

    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Password has been changed successfully.',
    ], 200);
})->middleware('auth:sanctum')->name('password.change');


Have you tried:
$user = $request->user();
$user->name = 'blah blah'; //for debug purpose
$user->password = bcrypt('password');
$user->save();

dd($user->refresh);


use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

Route::post('/change-password', function (Request $request) {
    // Validate the request data
    $request->validate([
        'current_password' => 'required|string',
        'new_password' => 'required|string|confirmed|min:8',
    ]);

    // Get the currently authenticated user
    $user = $request->user();

    // Check if the current password matches the user's current password
    if (!Hash::check($request->current_password, $user->password)) {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'The provided current password does not match your current password.',
        ], 422);
    }

    // Update the user's password
    $user->password = Hash::make($request->new_password); 
    $user->save(); // Make sure save() is actually persisting changes

    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Password has been changed successfully.',
    ], 200);
})->middleware('auth:sanctum')->name('password.change');

Important points to note:

make use of Hash::make() instead of bcrypt. It handles hashing correctly with laravel default configuration
make sure that $request->user() is returning authenticated user
make sure that auth:sanctum middleware is applied correctly.

You can clear your cache with these:

php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear

and then try re-run your code
